# MySQL database select data between two dates only pulling back from day and not month/year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to pull a count of data from a database between two dates by using a stored procedure using the below code:

```
 select count(*)
 from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd
 where bmd.Metric_Year >= startYear and bmd.Metric_Year <= endYear and 
 Metric_Month >= startMonth and Metric_Month <= endMonth and 
 bmd.Metric_Day >= startDay and bmd.Metric_Day <= endDay and 
 bmd.Board_Metrics_ID = 1 and bmd.Value_Colour = "Red" and
 bmd.Date_Created = (select max(bmd2.Date_Created)
                      from SOMT_Development.Board_Metrics_Data bmd2
                      where bmd2.Board_Metrics_ID = bmd.Board_Metrics_ID and
                            bmd2.Metric_Year = bmd.Metric_Year and
                            bmd2.Metric_Month = bmd.Metric_Month and
                            bmd2.Metric_Day = bmd.Metric_Day
                     )) as 'red'
```

However when the months/years are different it does not work correctly. This is the data that comes back if I input the dates for 2018-3-1 and 2018-4-4

```
 2018-03-29 09:46:20    green   1   no_comment  2018    3   1
 2018-03-29 09:46:20    red     1   no_comment  2018    3   2
 2018-03-29 09:46:20    white   1   no_comment  2018    3   3
 2018-03-29 09:46:20    white   1   no_comment  2018    3   4
 2018-04-04 13:25:19    green   1   no_comment  2018    4   4
 2018-04-02 13:25:30    green   1   no_comment  2018    4   2
 2018-04-03 13:25:47    green   1   no_comment  2018    4   3
```

As you can see, the days does not go up to the end of the month, it just goes up to the 4th day.

Thanks

Comment: if you compare the different date parts you'll always get problems when you have to compare dates over month end or year end

Comment: better compare the whole date if possible

Comment: hi @niyou I cannot do the whole date as inputting of the data cannot be changed from this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @niyou said, you will run into problems comparing the parts of a date separately, so you need to put them together into a whole date. So try replacing

```
bmd.Metric_Year >= startYear and bmd.Metric_Year <= endYear and 
 Metric_Month >= startMonth and Metric_Month <= endMonth and 
 bmd.Metric_Day >= startDay and bmd.Metric_Day <= endDay
```

with

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', bmd.Metric_Year, bmd.Metric_Month, bmd.Metric_Day), '%Y-%c-%e') >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', startYear, startMonth, startDay), '%Y-%c-%e') AND
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', bmd.Metric_Year, bmd.Metric_Month, bmd.Metric_Day), '%Y-%c-%e') <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', endYear, endMonth, endDay), '%Y-%c-%e')
```

Depending on the format of the values in your database, you may need to change the `%Y-%c-%e` format string to match, the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) will assist in selecting the right string.